# increment function in plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

In most programming languages you have a fast way to write an increment for a variable like the following examples:

```
inc(variableName);
variableName++;
variableName += 1;
```

Which ways are there in Oracle Pl/Sql to do this instead of using the following:

```
variableName := variableName + 1;
```

Comment: Do not use `SQL` tag for `PL/SQL` specific questions. They are different.

Comment: What's wrong with using `variableName := variableName + 1;`?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with it, it just a lot of typing (or copy pasting)
variableName++; is much shorter and in c++ you can use that immediately when you use the variable like arrayName[variableName++] := 'some text';

Comment: PL/SQL is a bit err ... _old-fashioned_ and sometimes a quite verbose when compared to more modern languages. You just have to get used to it as there is usually no way around it (and if there is away around it's likely much worse than the original one). The powers of PL/SQL lays in the SQL part.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The operators are listed [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/fundamentals.htm#LNPLS00206).

There is no equivalent of `++` or `+=`. I'm afraid you have to do it the long way.

You could write your own `inc()` function but that would probably make your code less readable to others as it would be non-standard.