# Oracle - Is there a compound assignment (+=)

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to update many number columns, must I repeat column name

```
update TABLENAME set COLUMN1 = COLUMN1 + ?, COLUMN2 = COLUMN2 + ?
```

Or is there a compound assignment as in [java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html)

```
update TABLENAME set COLUMN1 +=  ?,COLUMN2 +=  ?
```

> You can also combine the arithmetic operators with the simple assignment operator to create compound assignments. For example, x+=1;

If not, is there an enhancement of such requirement?

This isn't duplicate of [similar PLSQL question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28606855/increment-function-in-plsql), I ask about Oracle SQL

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28606855/266304), but probably not a duplicate as this is about SQL rather than PL/SQL. The SQL operators [are also in the documentaion](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Arithmetic-Operators.html), of course.

Comment: @AlexPoole - perhaps the ISO committee would consider adding compute/assign operators and curly braces in the next iteration of the standard. :-|

Comment: Possibly, though something like `set col1 += 1, col2 = col1` might be more confusing than now; and then there's `set col2 = col1++` ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no `+=`, `-=`, etc operators in SQL or PL/SQL.

Comment: Thank you, How can this change be suggested?

Comment: @user7294900: if you want that in Oracle you need to create an feature request with Oracle - good luck with that. If you want it in SQL, you need to convince the standards committee to include that into the language.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - ...and then you have to convince Oracle that they need to support it sooner rather than later. This is what is known in "The Hitchiker's Guide To The Galaxy" as "a recreational impossibility".